# Spring Boot 2 with Lombok and application.yml log level by package setting does not work

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, config, log4j2, lombok

I try to use the combination of Spring Boot 2 and Lombok to create a Log4j2 Logger (@Log4j2).
This is working.

Now I add a log level for a specific class in the application.yml (YAML not properties!). This is NOT working:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    my.poc.package.MyClass: DEBUG
```

Now I remove the class name so that only the package name remains as a key.
This does also NOT work:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    my.poc.package: DEBUG
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your project to use Log4j 2 instead of Logback? By default Spring uses Logback so you would be configuring Logback with those settings. But since your class uses Log4j2 it wouldn't know about it.